# Coldfusion SerializeJSON creating blank values

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to use SerializeJSON() to turn an instance of CFC into a string, whcih I can store in a database and then pull back out again later on.

The problem I'm having is using the following code:

```
<cfdump var="#THIS#">

    <!--- Convert CFC to JSON --->
    <cfset thisJSON = SerializeJSON(THIS)>

    <cfdump var="#DeserializeJSON(thisJSON)#">
```

Gives me the following:

[image: CFDump of THIS and after Serialize/DeSerialize process]

The red dump shows the CFC, with an array called `controls` with 7 items in it, each is another simpler CFC. When I run `serializeJSON` and then dump the result of that after passing it back through `deserializeJSON`, items 3 - 7 have become empty strings.

Here's the JSON:

```
{
    "MESSAGE":"",
    "CONTROLS":            
    [
        {
            "INDEX":"1.0",
            "NAME":"maxP11D",
            "SELWHERE":"",
            "DEF":"7940.0",
            "MMD":true,
            "ORDER":"7",
            "APP":"",
            "PRE":"",
            "MAXCAP":"35946.0",
            "FORMAT":"pound",
            "VALUE":"",
            "DESC":"List price exc FRF & VED",
            "MINCAP":"7939.0",
            "MINVAL":"7939.0",
            "MAXVAL":"35946.0",
            "TYPE":"range",
            "TITLE":"P11D"
        },            
        {
            "INDEX":"2.0",
            "NAME":"Y13Taxat22",
            "SELWHERE":"",
            "DEF":"0.0",
            "MMD":true,
            "ORDER":"6",
            "APP":" pa",
            "PRE":"Tax at 20%",
            "MAXCAP":"1904.1099853515625",
            "FORMAT":"pound",
            "DESC":"Personal tax rate",
            "VALUE":"",
            "MINVAL":"0",
            "MINCAP":"0.0",
            "MAXVAL":"1904.1099853515625",
            "TYPE":"range",
            "TITLE":"Company car tax"
        },
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    "SELECTRESTRICT":"
        (taxtype<6)AND (t.Make=@Peugeot@)\r\nAND t.model NOT LIKE @%407%@\r\nAND
        t.model NOT LIKE @% old@\r\nAND t.model != @107 3 door@\r\nAND
        t.model != @107 5 door@\r\nORDER BY \r\nt.model = @%iOn%@ 
        DESC,\r\nt.model = @107 3 door New@ DESC,\r\nt.model = @107 5 door New@
        DESC,\r\nt.model LIKE @%207%@ DESC,\r\nt.model LIKE @%RCZ%@
        DESC,\r\nt.model LIKE @%308%@ DESC,\r\nt.model LIKE @%3008%@
        DESC,\r\nt.model LIKE @%4007%@ DESC,\r\nt.model = @508 Saloon@
        DESC,\r\nt.model = @508 SW@ DESC,\r\nt.model = @508 RXH@ 
        DESC,\r\nt.model LIKE @%5008%@ DESC,\r\nt.model LIKE @%807%@
        DESC,\r\nt.model LIKE @%Bipper%@ DESC,\r\nt.model LIKE @%Partner%@
        DESC,\r\nt.model ASC
    ",      
    "SHOWNOTES":true,
    "MYSQL": {         
        "WHERE":"",
        "COLS":"
            t.maxP11D, t.Y13Taxat22, t.Y13Taxat40, t.CO2gpkm,
            t.fuelConsumptionDf, t.bodyStyle, t.fuelType, 
        ",
        "EXCLUDE":""
    }
}
```

Why would the first 2 items convert successfully but the remaining 5 change into strings?

I'm positive this code used to work, I have very recently upgraded to CF 9.0.1, has anyone else had a problem with JSON in 9.0.1?

Comment: I think we'd need to see the blurred out part of the components. I also think perhaps doing <cfoutput>#thisJSON#</cfoutput> might give you further clues.

Comment: The blurred out part is just the path to the component, like "path.to.component", as in `var t = new path.to.component()`. And I did a dump of `#thisJSON#`, and the controls array looks something like this: `"CONTROLS":[{...},{...},"","","","",""]`, so you can see the 5 items at the end of the json string are just blank strings

Comment: so no special characters, no underscores... just blah + . + blah + . + blah() for all of them right? And they all look identical for form? I guess I'm looking for something not standard that the parser might choke on or evaluate incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, I get you're point a bit more now. I'll add the complete dump to the original post

Comment: Ok... what is the "NAME" property of the third item in the array?

Comment: It's "Y13Taxat40". Element 2 and 3 are very similar, they are 20% and 40% tax figures. I can update the screen shot to show the contents of the array

Comment: That doesn't seem like a problem to me :)  ... ok... what happens if you take out the 2nd method? Does it serialize then? Of try one at a time?  Gotta figure out if it's a particular method, or the number of methods or whatever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are some major problem with serializeJSON in ACF 9. Make sure that you have cumlative hot fix 2 installed:

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/cumulative-hot-fix-2-coldfusion-1.html

In all honesty though, serializeJSON is a POS. I've been using an old project called CFJSON and haven't has any issues with it. I would suggest just switching over to that and forget about serializeJSON:

http://www.epiphantastic.com/cfjson/

Comment: Hmm the thing about that, is that I'm sure it worked when it was CF9, after upgrading to CF9.0.1, it's stopped working. I suppose that supports your argument for the Hot Fix. I'll try that

Comment: I believe this is a CF9 bug.  I had the same issue after installing HF2.  Had to uninstall CF9, reinstall CF9, update to CF901 and apply HF1 to fix.  Seems like HF1 is the only version that it actually works.

Comment: Hotfix 2 did fix this! I applied hotfix 2, but I didn't clear my browser cache, so the cookies I had before the hotfix with the incomplete JSON were still hanging around. It took a while for my cache to clear but then it became obvious that the Coldfusion Hotfix 2 fixed this problem! All just in time for Coldfusion 10 to be released. Oh well, thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Are you married to using serializeJson(), or - if all you're after is serialising an object - would [objectSave()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSf01dbd23413dda0e613c53881225a218cab-7fff.html) be a better option?

Comment: It's going into a database so using serializeJSON to create a string made things nice and easy, coupled with deserializeJSON. The ID of the stored serialized object is held in the session, I suppose I could just store the name of the file that object was saved to instead, although I'd want to delete the files when they were no longer needed, which seems like it would be harder to do than the DB approach

Comment: Why would you be saving the object to a file if you don't want it as a file?  Just save it to a binary object, convert it to base 64, store it as a string.  When wanting it back again, read it from the DB and convert it back to binary with toBinary(), and to an object with objectLoad().  It's more steps than using JSON, but it has the benefit of using the right tool for the intended job.  Plus it *works*... if you serialise then deserialise an object using serializeJson(), you don't end up with an object, you end up with a struct.  Not the same thing.

Comment: I gave that a try, but it's getting truncated in the MySQL database, and then I'm getting a java.io.EOFException using objectLoad. I think I might need to rethink how this CFC is built

Comment: I'd say that's more to do with your DSN configuration or your DB schema than a problem with the serialisation.  Not that you were specifically saying it was not that, I guess.

Comment: I tried using a MySQL longblob but that didn't seem to help. I'll look in more detail at the string that's being sent in/out of the DB and see at which point it gets truncated.